# I can't scale the size of UV texture image

Tags: uv

I was making this tile following a tutorial.
I was usually able to scale UV texture simply in the UV editor screen.
However this time, although I did the scaling as I wanted the tiles to appear bigger and larger, it looks exactly the same, very dense. 
How can I fix it?
Thank you so much!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 UV sets. So to use one of them put `UV map` node in material, and select right one:

[image]

Then, connect `UV map` node to textures:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've been stuck here for days :S You saved me!

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers